# SQL/VBA - if/then/else for day of year when recordset has Leap Years and non Leap Years

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Good Morning,

Here is my issue. I have a form where the user selects the date they want to work with. From there, in vba, I store the entered date in a variable (ytdDate) and then the day of year for that date is stored as a variable (dayOfYear). These variable values are then used in the following sql statement:

```
    sqlYTDCounts = "SELECT Count(x.event_unique_id) AS total, 
                    Year(occurrence_date) AS year " & _
                   "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT event_unique_id, occurrence_date 
                    FROM events WHERE datepart('y',occurrence_date) <=" & 
                    dayOfYear & _
                    ")  AS x GROUP BY Year(occurrence_date) HAVING 
                    (((Year([occurrence_date]))>='" & _
                    DatePart("YYYY", ytdDate) - 10 & "') )"
```

So essentially what is happening is a recordset is retrieved where the day of the year for each [occurrence_date] is <= the day of the year from the date the user selected on the form.

The sql works great, but only for non Leap Years, for all Leap Years it is actually getting the day of the year before that from user selected date. As an example:

User selects July 23,2017

dayOfYear = 204

But for a Leap Year July 23rd is the 205th day of the year.

In my head, the solution seems simple enough: From the recordset check to see if the year of the occurrence is any of these years (2004,2008,2012,2016) and if the day of the year of the occurrence_date for that occurrence is >= 60 (the reason being is I can't just check if it is a leap year because LY and NonLY have the same day of year up until 60).

If both of these criteria are met, then the <=" & dayOfYear &_ part of the sql statement would be <=" & (dayOfYear + 1) & _

If non of the criteria are met then sql statement would remain as is.

Now, how to translate that into VBA is where I am stuck. I have tried using IF THEN ELSE statements with the sql statement but that hasn't worked (I am pretty sure I am not doing it correctly) =]

I really apologize if this is super convoluted and not making any sense, but any and all input/suggestions/assistance is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Why do you need to bother with day of year at all?  Why not use `WHERE occurrence_date BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(ytdDate), 1, 1) AND ytdDate`?

Comment: Why not just query up to the date for each year rather than counting the number of days? If you use DateAdd("yyyy",-1,occurrence_date) it will give you the date a year ago?

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks for your input. I will try that now.

Comment: @MintyThanks bud. I will try that after I try BaconBits suggestion.

Comment: @BaconBits When I tried it I received the following error: Syntax error in number in query expression 'occurrence_date BETWEEN 2017.01.01 and 2017.07.2' For some reason the last digit is getting cut off.

Comment: Well, remember that date literals in Access queries need to look like `#2017.01.01#` or similar with `#` surrounding them.  If you can't use parameterized queries (and it's been too long since I've touched VBA in Access to recall) then you should format your dates like that.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks, I will give that a shot. One other thing though, the select statement needs to grab all years as far back as 2002, but the BETWEEN only applies to 2017. How would it iterate through each year using the same BETWEEN but with the respective year (rather than 2017)?

Comment: You need to specify January 1 of the specified year.  That's what `DateSerial(Year(ytdDate), 1, 1)` is intended to do.

Comment: @BaconBits ok, thanks. I will keep plugging away

Comment: @Minty apologies for not completely understanding your suggestions. From my original sql statement, how does your DateAdd work into it? Am I adding, replacing? Thanks.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you want to get the same data for each preceding year up to same the current day of the year? eg 2017 \01\01 to 2017\07\25 and then 2016\01\01 to 2016\07\25 ?

Comment: @BaconBits For the life of me I can't get vba to stop trimming the last character off the WHERE clause. Whether I put # around the dates vba will not include the last # on the ytdDate. If I don't use # then vba trims the last digit off of ytdDate. If I wrap the WHERE clause in brackets, vba trims the last bracket off the clause. Weird.

Comment: @Minty That is correct, I want to count the distinct event_unique_id's for each year from Jan 01 to the date selected by the user on the form (i.e. July 25). This would then guarantee that the counts are for the exact date, rather than the day of the year which is clearly affected by Leap Years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method using *DateAdd* which always handles leap years correctly:

```
sqlYTDCounts = _
    "SELECT Count(*) AS total, Year(occurrence_date) AS year " & _
    "FROM " & _
    "    (SELECT DISTINCT event_unique_id, occurrence_date " & _
    "    FROM events " _
    "    WHERE DateDiff('d', DateAdd('yyyy', " & Year(ytdDate) & " - Year(occurrence_date), occurrence_date), occurrence_date) <= 0) AS x " & _ 
    "GROUP BY Year(occurrence_date) " & _
    "HAVING Year([occurrence_date]) >= " & Year(ytdDate) & " - 10)"
```

Edit2:

```
sqlYTDCounts = _
    "SELECT Count(*) AS total, Year(occurrence_date) AS year " & _
    "FROM " & _
    "    (SELECT DISTINCT event_unique_id, occurrence_date " & _
    "    FROM events " & _
    "    WHERE DateDiff('d', DateAdd('yyyy', " & Year(ytdDate) & " - Year(occurrence_date), occurrence_date), #" & Format(ytdDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) >= 0) AS x " & _ 
    "GROUP BY Year(occurrence_date) " & _
    "HAVING Year([occurrence_date]) >= " & Year(ytdDate) & " - 10"
```

Comment: thanks @Gustav I put your method in and it does generate counts but they are way off (I can run the query correctly using php (for the dashboard)). The current year count is fine, but then all the other years are double what they are supposed to be. I only want to count the distinct event_unique_id

Comment: sorry @Gustav, I tried to edit my response but it wouldn't let me. Anyway, I discovered that the reason the counts are off is because the query is doing it for the entire year, rather than YTD. So each year has its yearly total. Is there a way to make sure it only goes as far as the year to date? Thanks

Comment: Sounds right. It should compare with `ytdDate` ... see edited answer.

Comment: thanks for the edited answer. I added the ampersand that was missing before the underscore on the "FROM events" line. However, when I run it with the edited version it brings up the error "Invalid SQL statement: expected 'DELETE','INSERT','PROCEDURE','SELECT',or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: I've corrected the code. Is seems valid, so please print out the resulting SQL for us to see. It runs perfectly fine here.

Comment: Thanks again. So, the code is valid and it does run. But the counts are off. In fact, 2017 doesn't even show up. Here is the resulting SQL Statement when I click the "SQL" view for the query:        SELECT Count(x.event_unique_id) AS total, Year(occurrence_date) AS [year]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT event_unique_id, occurrence_date     FROM Shootings     WHERE DateDiff('d', DateAdd('yyyy', 2017 - Year(occurrence_date), occurrence_date), #2017/07/25#) <= 0)  AS x
GROUP BY Year(occurrence_date)
HAVING (((Year([occurrence_date]))>=2017-10));

Comment: please disregard the incorrect table name I had listed in the code I just posted. The proper table is events, I was just running this code on various tables. So the incorrect count totals still stands. I am doing what I can on my end to figure this out. Any further guidance you can provide is, as it has been, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I reversed the DateDiff comparison - please see edited answer. Edit2.

Comment: my gratitude toward your assistance is boundless. I truly appreciate you taking the time, and having the patience, to work this out with me. Thanks!!